# Calling custom view from main activity.. Message in onDraw() is printed but custom view is not rendered

Tags: android, render, android-custom-view, ondraw

I have two classes - MainActivity.java and MainView.java.

I'm trying to render a custom view (defined in MainView.java) when screen is touched from the main activity.

My code is doing a funky thing. From the main page, when you touch the screen, it does NOT render the custom view I've specified in MainView.java - but still prints out a message I put in the onDraw() method, which should mean that onDraw() is being run. Why is my onDraw() method being run but its view doesn't render?

Also, both my onTouchEvent in MainActivity.java and MainView.java seems to respond at the same time, although the view I see is the only the activity_main.xml.

Please help :(

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.owner.thesisapp;

import com.example.owner.thesisapp.MainView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static HashMap soundPoolMap;
private static int S1 = R.raw.a3v1;
private static int S2 = R.raw.c3v1;
private static int S3 = R.raw.dsharp3v1;
private static int S4 = R.raw.fsharp3v1;
private int soundID;
private boolean isSoundLoaded = false;

public MainView mainView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainView = (MainView) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {
            isSoundLoaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.fsharp3v1, 1);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    if (isSoundLoaded) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.d("Test", "Played sound");
    }

    mainView.postInvalidate();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
// Keep landscape orientation
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // ignore orientation/keyboard change
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

MainView.java

```
package com.example.owner.thesisapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Owner on 6/1/2015.
 */
public class MainView extends View {

Bitmap stillWave;
int iy = 0;

public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    stillWave = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wave);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    Log.d("MAINVIEW: Is this ran?", " ");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("Action DOWN!", " ");
            iy = 0;
            this.invalidate();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("Action MOVE!", " ");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("Action UP!", " ");
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Log.d("MAINVIEW ONDRAW: Is this ran?", " ");

    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();

    //set background
    Rect wBackground = new Rect();
    wBackground.set(0, 0, width, height);
    Paint pBackground = new Paint();
    pBackground.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    pBackground.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(wBackground, pBackground);

    //Log.d("garo, sero", width + " " + height);

    //set Wave
    Paint pWave = new Paint();
    pWave.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    pWave.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pWave.setStrokeWidth(10);
    pWave.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    int waveFlucMin = -100;
    int waveFlucMax = 100;

    float[] coords = new float[width * 2];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < width; ix++) {
        int yoffset = waveFlucMin + (int) (Math.random() * ((waveFlucMax - waveFlucMin) + 1));
        coords[2 * ix] = (float) ix;
        coords[2 * ix + 1] = (float) iy + yoffset;
    }
    //Log.d("Coordinates x?", coords[1] + " " + coords[3] + " " + coords[5] + " " + coords[7] + " " + coords[301] + " " + coords[303] + " ");
    //Log.d("Coordinates y?", coords[0] + " " + coords[2] + " " + coords[4] + " " + coords[6] + " " + coords[300] + " " + coords[302] + " ");
    //Log.d("Generating?", "YES, generating forloop   : " + iy);
    //wait a second between each wave generation
    /*
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    */

    drawWave(coords, width, pWave, canvas);

    if (iy < height) {
        iy += 10;
        invalidate();
    } else {
        //do nothing - finish onDraw() call.
    }

}

private void drawWave(float[] coords, int width, Paint pWave, Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPoints(coords, 0, width*2, pWave);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.example.owner.thesisapp.MainView
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#111C64"/>
```

Comment: try removing this `setWillNotDraw(false);` unless your extending from view group you don't need that line

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your layout. Both your custom `View` and the `ImagView` are, since your are using a `RelativeLayout`, aligned to the Top left. The z order in this case put the `ImageView` on top on your custom `View` and, since it is taking the whole screen, you can't see your custom view.

Comment: `match_parent` and `fill_parent` for both views. I Missed that